# Displaying Categories By order and Moving Categories to Specific Order

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing order of records from the front end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320946/changing-order-of-records-from-the-front-end)

I AM Displaying categories in ASC order there are arrows  up / down i wrote the code to move category up or down order

In my database i am maintaining a column 'listorder' where i am maintaining all orders now i need to make another function in which i am  displaying a text field for user input and a button against each category where user can input and press move button and category will be moved to that specific input now my problem lets say

Category A has list_order **1** 
Category B has list_order **2** 
Category C has list_order **3** 
Category D has list_order **4**

i want to move category **D** to **B**  so i will update list_order of Category D to **2** but how can i update all other categories order using php/mysql
like i have to make CAT B list_order to 3 and Category C to list_order 4 imagine there are so many categories so how can i manage this ? i can do this by updating row one by one but i dont think that is quite right approach

Answer (score 0):

You need to update all the categories in between.

You first need to move all the other rows down by one, and then you put Category D on it's right place.

Check this out:

```
mysql> select * from categories order by list_order;
+----+------------+------------+
| id | name       | list_order |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 | Category A |          1 |
|  2 | Category B |          2 |
|  3 | Category C |          3 |
|  4 | Category D |          4 |
+----+------------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> update categories set list_order = list_order + 1 where list_order >= 2;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 3  Warnings: 0

mysql> update categories set list_order = 2 where id = 4;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from categories order by list_order;
+----+------------+------------+
| id | name       | list_order |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 | Category A |          1 |
|  4 | Category D |          2 |
|  2 | Category B |          3 |
|  3 | Category C |          4 |
+----+------------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This is what i wanted actually and it works when i move a category down to up  but when i move id from top to down what it happens is it makes the order like this 2 , 3 ,4 ,5  @Andrés Gattinoni  i think i have to also check if its less than max order 
<br>
UPDATE compecat set listorder=listorder+1 where listorder >=3 AND id !='1'<br>
UPDATE compecat set listorder='3' where id='1' LIMIT 1<br>

Comment: Yes, you should make all the appropriate validations, I just wanted to give you a general idea on how to work this out.

Answer (score 0):

Quick & dirty (but quite universal) php function to change order of given element and all that should also be moved. Works in both directions and affects only rows withing old and new position.

```
function changeOrder($id, $newPosition, $table = 'category', $sortCol = 'list_order'){
    $oldPosition = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT {$sortCol} FROM {$table} WHERE id={$id} LIMIT 1"));
    $oldPosition = $oldPosition[0];
    $operators = ((int)$oldPosition >= (int)$newPosition)?array('+','<=','>='):array('-','>=','<=');
    $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$sortCol} = IF(id={$id},{$newPosition},{$sortCol} {$operators[0]} 1) 
            WHERE {$sortCol} {$operators[1]} {$oldPosition} AND {$sortCol} {$operators[2]} {$newPosition}";
    return mysql_query($sql)?mysql_affected_rows():FALSE;
}
```